# how can add input from user to get the answer of the power

Tags: python-3.x

how can add input from user to get the answer of the power of the number he want / what can I add or remove ?
i have add the input as shown but still doesn't work if there is any other way ?

```
def raise_to_power ((num1==input("enter your numeber"))), (num2==input("enter your second numeber"))):
     
     result = 1
     for index in range (num2):
       result = result * num1
     return result


print (raise_to_power(num1,num2 ))
```

Comment: In case you didn't know `**` is the "raise-to-power" operator, e.g. `return num1 ** num2`.

Comment: unfortunately the answer i got wasnt working still !

Comment: That tells us nothing about your new attempt.  Did you convert the inputs to floats?  `a=float(input()); b=float(input()); c = a ** b`.  That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some syntactic and logical errors.

1. You probably were trying to create global variables by doing `(num1==input("enter your numeber"))), (num2==input("enter your second numeber"))` since you try to use `num1` and `num2` when calling the function. You should do this with the assignment operator (`=`, assigns variables), not the equality operator (`==`, checks if two things are equal) **outside** of your function definition.
2. `input()` returns a `str`, and you cannot multiply an `int` (`result`, which is 1) by a `str`. You should convert it to a `float`.

---

Here it is fixed:

```py
def raise_to_power(num1: float | int, num2: int):
     result = 1
     for index in range(num2):
       result = result * num1
     return result

num1 = float(input("Enter your first number. "))
num2 = int(input("Enter your second number. "))

print(raise_to_power(num1, num2))
```

---

Lastly, it's worth noting that the `**` operator exists to facilitate exponentiation, so your entire function body can be replaced with `return num1 ** num2`. However, I recognize that you may have had other motivations for trying to make this function, such as getting a good understanding of Python's syntax. If that is the case, hopefully the corrected function was able to help you.

Comment: It really doesn't make sense for user input to be part of the *definition* of the function. It would be a lot better to either move that inside the function body (and for there to be no arguments), or for it to be part of the function *call*, rather than the definition.

Comment: Yes, but I am basing it off of what OP wrote. I'll edit to add your recommendation.

Comment: I did not downvote, but why not just `return num1 ** num2`?

Comment: @JonSG I did let the OP know of the `**` operator at the end of my answer, but an answer of just "use **" may not be useful to them. Perhaps they are using this as Python practice. This answer addresses their misunderstandings.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work

Comment: @XboxOne `for index in range(num2)` won't work if `num2` is a `float`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen oops nice catch. I guess OP wanted `num2` to be an `int`. Updated.

Comment: @SamEMRAN can you give more details as to what goes wrong?

Comment: I cant run the code

Comment: I'm not sure what that's supposed to mean... Are you getting some error? Are you confused as to how to run a Python file? Please elaborate.